# Index references off by two pages

Tags: indexing

Never seen this before but I have a 400 page latex manuscript where the index references are 2 pages off. Eg they should reference page n, but the index gives n-2. I noticed that if I comment out the first chapter heading, the index gives the correct page numbers. I'm not expecting an answer but clues as to where I should start looking for the culprit and what that might be?

Comment: Is there anything special in this first chapter? Did you change any settings there?

Comment: just to verify the obvious -- you did rerun latex after running makeindex?  are the page values in the `.idx` file the same as in the "final" index?  if not, that's a sure sign that the makeindex step was omitted.

Comment: Yes I do, I have a batch file that does the work. Still string to find the issue by removing chunks of text until it works.

Comment: I have a solution but I have no idea why it works, if I use the option -p 1 in makeindex then the numbering is correct.

Comment: `-p 1` doesn't make sense.  the man page for makeindex says that this affects the starting page number of the *index*, not the page numbers referred to *in* the index.  (i wasn't aware of this switch; have to explore it further.)

Comment: I've no idea either but I spend a good 2 hours trying to solve this problem, I'll return to it another time but had to use -p even though I don't know how it works because I had a deadline to meet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **imakeidx** package instead.

I'm using bookdown and ran into the very same issue. My book was exactly 400 pages and all indices were off by 2 pages (n-2).

I switched to the **imakeidx** package in my preamble and left everything else the same. Now, all pages in the index are correct.

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
```